# XOR clause in (positive) standard form

Tags: boolean-logic, xor, solver, sat, satisfiability

I'm struggling with following XOR clause transformation:

This XOR clause is given:

```
(x1 ⊕ ¬x2 ⊕ x3)
```

translated into CNF, it is:

```
(¬x1 ∨ ¬x2 ∨ ¬x3)∧(¬x1 ∨ x2 ∨ x3)∧(x1 ∨ ¬x2 ∨ x3)∧(x1 ∨ x2 ∨ ¬x3)
```

This is clear.

But why is `(x1 ⊕ ¬x2 ⊕ x3) = (x1 ⊕ x2 ⊕ x3 ⊕ 1)` ? <-this is called the XOR clause in "standard form"

and why is `(x1 ⊕ x2 ⊕ x3 ⊕ 1) <=> x1 ⊕ x2 ⊕ x3 = 0`?

I don't get it...

Here's another quote from the paper I got this: "An xor-clause is in the standard form if all of its literals appear in the positive phase."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prove `(x1 ⊕ ¬x2 ⊕ x3) = (x1 ⊕ x2 ⊕ x3 ⊕ 1)`

Take the RHS,

```
(x1 ⊕ x2 ⊕ x3 ⊕ 1) 
(x1 ⊕ x2 ⊕ 1 ⊕ x3) (⊕ is associative)
(x1 ⊕ ((x2 ∧ ¬1) ∨ (¬x2 ∧ 1)) ⊕ x3) (⊕ definition)
(x1 ⊕ (0 ∨ (¬x2 ∧ 1)) ⊕ x3) (Null)
(x1 ⊕ (¬x2 ∧ 1) ⊕ x3) (Identity)
(x1 ⊕ ¬x2 ⊕ x3) (Identity)
```

Which is equal to the LHS. Hence they are logically equivalent.

Comment: Ok thank you, very nice answer. I understand it. But I'm still struggling with this notation: 'x1 ⊕ x2 ⊕ x3 = 0'. Why is this the same then '(x1 ⊕ x2 ⊕ x3 ⊕ 1)' ?

Comment: @random-user From your updated question, `(x1 ⊕ x2 ⊕ x3 ⊕ 1) <=> x1 ⊕ x2 ⊕ x3 = 0` -> Form what I can gather from the context, I think this is trying to say that `(x1 ⊕ x2 ⊕ x3 ⊕ 1)` is not logically equivalent to `x1 ⊕ x2 ⊕ x3`. This can be proved with manipulation of the equation (which will be tedious) or by assuming they are logically equivalent and proving by counter-example. Ie. A counter-example is `x1, x2, x3 = 0`